# Statement in which already moves a value to register at compile time

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

Well, in the code example below, the variable i, will have an instruction to be allocated in the register even before linking, how does the compiler know that it will have registers available at runtime, even before loading the program into memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//File f.c

int main(void)
{
  int i = 5;
  printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Disassembly of the f.o file

```
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
main:
    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     esi, 5
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

Comment: Who do you think might use your registers? If the compiler does not create any code to allocate registers for variables, how would a register ever be used? As you compile for a given CPU architecture the compiler should know rather well, how many and which registers are available to use.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, he knows that, but how does he do it? I don't understand computer architecture mt, for example let's say you already have a program running which uses the esi register, how does the compiler know that the esi register is being used by another program? Or there is the possibility of two or more programs using the same register, but each one with its own cpu time, as I said before, I'm pretty noob.

Comment: ehm, because it is what it does. the number of available registers is known (for each processor) and its compiler's job to use them, i.e., to say which values to write there. it is also compiler's job to know that this variable only exists within a function, it is initialized only once, so it actually can be optimized away. Basics of how compiler work take at least one book to explain.

Comment: Because the OS's task scheduler stores the registers before switching tasks, and restores them afterwards. So the compiler has no need to know what other process is using which registers.

Comment: We don't care what other programs might be running. It is job of the OS to create a defined environment. The calling conventions or Application Binaries Interfaces (ABI) define what registers may be used for what purpose. The compiler is designed to behave accordingly.

Comment: @YuriBittencourt when a program runs on a CPU, then it has a number of available registers which are not used by any other program at this time. At any single time there is only one program running on one (logical) CPU core. When programs switch, it is a job of the operating system to save the values of each register and then restore them. The program itself does not need to care about it. All this should be a part of processor's/OS specification which tells compiler what is available to him, after which the compiler allocates resources for the provided code.

Comment: The operating system specifies which registers are available for the program, and the compiler writer follows that specification

Comment: Um, I think I understand, in this case the cpu only actually runs one program, and the other programs are idle in the meantime, so in this case, if two programs have a runtime environment, and both programs use the esi register, for example, if program A is executed, cpu restores the value of that register does the operations and when it goes to program B, puts register esi on the stack, and then restores the value of register esi of program B, would that be it? @effenok

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable simplified description.  And the result is that as far as program A is concerned, it appears as if nobody else is using register esi (or any of the others), and its value will be preserved until program A itself executes an instruction that overwrites it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, one question, it has nothing to do with the topic at hand, but could you recommend me good math books to understand books like The Art Of Programming ? I saw that you are a mathematician, grateful. @NateEldredge

Comment: You mean Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*?  The math used there is a fairly wide range and I am not sure there would be a single book to cover all of it.  A good start would be an introductory discrete math text, perhaps [*Discrete Mathematics: An Open Introduction*](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3.html) by Oscar Levin, a colleague of mine.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's right, I forgot to write the word Computer, lol, thanks a lot for the tip, I'll see if I can buy this book to read, :)

Comment: @YuriBittencourt: The "Open" part means you don't have to buy it :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge kkkk, sorry I ended up not opening the link, but taking the name and throwing it on google to see the reviews, it was a quick look, glad it's free, anyway, thanks again, :)